# using ffmpeg to live stream to Youtube

Tags: ffmpeg

I created an app in Windows to live stream the content of all the screen or only a portion of it (a Windows) to Youtube.
I used this app but I still have a problem I'm not able to understand.
I use different internet connections: ADSL at home 30Mbit, or ADSL router outside ad 2.5Mbit.
In any case, after starting ffmpeg to live stream the fps strats growing from 300 to 2000 the transmission is perfect for some minutes, then the fps slowdown until a very low value for the bitrate of the Youtube streaming. The image is no more clear and disappears, the audio is still working. The CPU is still under the 35-40% of usage.
ffmpeg must be restarted to get another 5-7 minutes of good transmission.
I tryed changing the ffmpeg command line but nothing seams to influence this behaviour.
This is because I still don't undestand Where the problem is. Any suggestions?
A log of a single session (aprox. 20 minutes) is available here http://www.mbinet.it/public/ffmpeg-20180106-094446.txt 
Another (aprox. 5 min.) is available here http://www.mbinet.it/public/ffmpeg-20180106-105529.txt 
Thanks

Comment: Add ‘-re’ to ffmpeg command.

Comment: Thanks. It worked